# Replace row with NA if any values are non-positive

Tags: r, apply

My dataset is similar to below:

```
df <- data.frame(
     A = c(-1, 2, 3),
     B = c(1, 1, -1))
df
#    A  B
# 1 -1  1
# 2  2  1
# 3  3 -1
```

I am trying to get the following result where values are kept when both `A` and `B` are positive:

```
   A  B
1 NA  NA
2  2  1
3 NA  NA
```

I have tried `df2 <- apply(df, 1:2, function(x) if (x > 0) x else NA)`, but it returns value when either `A` or `B` is positive. How do I add the second condition to it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could multiply each column by a vector that takes value 1 if all values are positive in that row and otherwise takes value NA:

```
df * ifelse(rowSums(df <= 0) > 0, NA, 1)
#    A  B
# 1 NA NA
# 2  2  1
# 3 NA NA
```

Comment: That's brilliant! Two questions: 1. what does `rowSums(df <=0)`, whcih returns `1 0 1`, mean? 2. In my example, the `str` of `df2` is `num` whereas yours is `data.frame`. How to convert it to `num`? I need it for my next calculation.

Comment: @T-T 1) `df <= 0` returns a matrix indicating whether each element in `df` is non-positive, and `rowSums` sums the rows, converting `TRUE` to 1 and `FALSE` to 0. Therefore this counts the number of non-positive elements in each row. 2) You can wrap this in `as.matrix` to convert from data frame to matrix.

Answer (score 2):

`replicate(NCOL(df), Reduce('|', lapply(df, function(x) x < 0)))` can give the indices where `NA` should be substituted. It is checking if there is at least one value less than zero in each column.

```
replace(df, replicate(NCOL(df), Reduce('|', lapply(df, function(x) x < 0))), NA)
#   A  B
#1 NA NA
#2  2  1
#3 NA NA
```

Or

```
df[which(!rowSums(df >= 0) == NCOL(df)),] = NA
df
#   A  B
#1 NA NA
#2  2  1
#3 NA NA
```

Comment: This is a nice solution because it should work well in data frames where the data is non-numeric. My solution saves a bit of typing but would break down, say, on text data.